# Read parquet file column with Json String without hardcoding the Schema()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a parquet file in which one column is json

```
>>> sdf = spark.read.parquet('/hdfsData/ParquetString/*parquet')
>>> sdf.printSchema()
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

I have another file which has the json Data from which i need to infer the json Schema.

```
 df = spark.read.json('/hdfsData/sample.json')
 schema = df.schema

root
 |-- Updt: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- inv: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- avail: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- avl: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Idc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- StateCd: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- stateIdc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- trans: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- updateDT: string (nullable = true)
```

I wanted the output schema to be

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Updt: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- inv: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- avail: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- avl: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Idc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- StateCd: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- stateIdc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- trans: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- updateDT: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried few of the options, What is the best way to read this without hardcoding schema?

```
spark.sql("select from_json(cast (value as string),df1.schema.json) value,A.*from values A")
spark.sql("select from_json(cast (value as string),df1.schema.jsonValue()) value,timestamp from values")
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create the dynamically query before executing it:

```py
schema = df1.schema.simpleString()
query = "select from_json(value, %s) value, timestamp from values" % schema
spark.sql(query)
```

Comment: Thanks @kafels I will check on this and accept it accordingly